# Concatenation in a function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

Could someone explain to me what this code means and how it works? For example I have a table, STUDENTS:

```
gname   lname
-------------
vi23    kola
vi34    red
```

How does this concatenation function code work in relation to the table?

```
CREATE FUNCTION concat (text, text) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
t text;
BEGIN
IF character_length($1) &gt; 0 THEN
t = $1 ||', '|| $2;
ELSE
t = $2;
END IF;
RETURN t;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE pegar (
sfunc = concat,
basetype = text,
stype = text,
initcond = ''
);
```

Is it that the `$1` and `$2` are parameters for gname and lname respectively or they are equal to the basetype and stype in the agregate function pegar? What is happening in this code?

```
IF character_length($1) &gt; 0 THEN
    t = $1 ||', '|| $2;
    ELSE
    t = $2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sfunc` of an aggregate is called with the "state" argument and the next input (the type of the state argument is the `stype` setting) as the first and second (or more...) arguments ($1 and $2).

So this defines an aggregate where the state transition to aggregate a new value is to append it to the existing state (if defined).

How these map to columns depends on how you're calling the aggregate, which you don't show. But if you did `select pegar(lname) from t` then it would go as:

```
state= next=kola : output=kola
state=kola next=red : output=kola, red
```

With no `finalfunc` defined, the output of the aggregate is the last state: `kola, red`

Aggregate functions description: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it combines the column to `comma separated values`. so it will return `**vi23,kola**`

Comment: but what does $1 and $2 do are they colums???

Comment: $1 refers to the first argument, $2 to the second, and so on.

Comment: Hmm - I wonder if there is any sort of online manual that could help? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 0):

it takes two arguments and check whether first argument length is greater than 0 or not because if the length is 0 or less than 0 means there is no argument at all.if it is true then it concatenates the two arguments with the comma between them (concatenates with || operator) otherwise it will store the second argument as text